# cannot fetch some url with php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to extract html tags from url but some websites return unknown character...
I think url's with ajax programming have this problem...
this is my code

```
$url='http://www.varzesh3.com';
$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=5;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

// Get URL content
$lines_string=curl_exec($ch);
// close handle to release resources
curl_close($ch);
//output, you can also save it locally on the server
echo $lines_string;
```

it give me a string like this

```
�\��$k4l�r�9�gD�ŲB@z���{b�� ]�@��Vd�>\����Q��� F|$��;a���Sd^NLrev��>�lh�X�R�lH����Υ�L��>}t4%a�:�*��ѵd#�[��I�S'�O+���RJ�uC��N�jF�W,䩐��f>�g2QGv�?���q�������$�1����M�&�w�ˆ�p�E:�`iH�U��x��4#���M�RF�R/A���'��K�=�r� ;��2��NHC/��sQ&�VT�����0Қ�Q��@���ĄB���ʆ�,8T��bV^�*"#�@%2S�q��ks� � �%������Ɂ�u���y^]�$�X��&�l(�P)���&�i�KL�B*��\}��]C � |��.gń}{���d�91/'e��~^�͆���������o�J� S� �Ϣ;@�Ԙ֭Q#'D��"�L6.R���<�P������ �^��!����@��Dtk���%�Le.Q�YWD�K (��gxFD_�p,�C�@���]�2d�?�%xǏ�S�~m:��rO�N<�hz�l�䳡�b��ǉIq|UĐնr(^&�9�����#|������$Y���7��7祐 ,�y�>��"�E��s�y`�,����50�!�%�*���\�̥�t�LRf���$�����9=yFq���&��ɮ7 ����M�)�iv������3��H�� V�J�"(b5��-[�l��*���+��Z�mq��B���%�j�B�.�B�1Wͼ$��� �Q;�JZ>���]�n耔؃9=���Q�~���f.i�z��E�f7]�L�-j�祒 uX��=��>oө-�^����IL�E��]?���$E��K���y��{:�ڊ%��rUת�\�E���*���_C9�u��nGnb Qܘ� at~�d"=b.?F���}����b��G��/� �a�����.�b�Q�^q�}I���T�w�+hԄ ˈ�������gBP���!d�!�\ƅ$� �G:]�t�ЁUi��/����/�� zo��s����P4���Ua�!OC��8��!8}E�[r�3��#i@o��q$g�gC������+J��@��Q�׾&���J�����1�3�����t���^�����.�Ec�cN(7/J�A`����$m��f�b,��i3A���lh���TEC% ;��(��z�=��x!87�v!k� r" M%}�%v�PNtɁ�uX�CKZr�ܺ�heD?�� �Zth�z��q�+��?]�R���(���*!Z>\��K�����K�97���X�c��y��r5�����\D�.��e��v�$L�P'�3IXCQg&a�P��F6aa�(Z��g�À��{x,D� ���#�dѤ)3�t�La ��9gD������s��Ě#j�� � Q��h�N������c3"� �-�9������%*т�q:� d���"R��������\��p��NY$���$���B)�B���NѦ�w���g����M�|g4/�Ȥ����b� ����>��\�;�q7Ժ�M�AZ�lOJ۵U(D�Ȣ���jj5���/�2�*�͹�gC��Z9���O�?�B07_*�Ĳ��4�1+��˪I�Y�,@iP�~�×��;� 3AS�� �X�b�������k�;<�r���!|��h2��4Ӡ�"��3<��;6��[C�~�� ���Ǝ��*ܳ�5I6Ȣ(YUdd��φ��e�NK�o'��[��S����_On�Y�MU�`'��Y�tSa���_{���S̈́��z1�v�����%�W4��lJ��1�d�ժ�K�Z�P�TǉP�A����g.y�g@��@x�T(eB1E�VP�� 7K.c��j�D��;�F���~F���v���ۂ�y0��f:i<����"��Tt'����N��{G�_"5����Q{8�������p��z��+��������1v:qE*m=��9���A�s��r���FX1X�*P��)VW��@SĊrA�����
```

how can i solve it?...
I want contents inside HTML tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site link you've provided in your example, contains arabic words which requires utf-8. Also it returns gzipped data.

You can use header to support `utf-8` on your page

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and set `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to `gzip` in your curl request

Final Code should be

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$url='http://www.varzesh3.com';
$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=5;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

// We will set curl header to support utf-8 charset
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"));
// We will support gzip encoded data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");

// Get URL content
$lines_string=curl_exec($ch);
// close handle to release resources
curl_close($ch);
//output, you can also save it locally on the server
echo $lines_string;
```

Comment: unfortunately don't work...it retun this ??[s?q(????Z8l???Fw?}`r?vW?lKGG?}|??P?0?`?????&.V???~P,Drj?=?=????W?YU]???iW"???????>???????S???????O??{?�?e?;??m??O???w?a???[?F??n????W??N???f?=Z}?_mw???l???ta????i#W7{?+????{p?}??lu??q??* _a{o??????O???Vw=?????

Comment: I want contents inside html tags

Comment: tnx so much bro...it finally work...so can u tell me how can i change table inside it?

Comment: yes u r right...in homepage it has changeable table...how can I get different contents...

Comment: That's out of the context of this question.  I think you can use some kind of html parser like https://github.com/tburry/pquery

Answer (score -1):

Curl will get data if it is in specified format like json and xml.
But you are just write url but not specific url which send data as json or array or xml etc.

If you want to download whole website then try CURL using command line.

Comment: can u give me an example?